# Progamming contracts in Ethereum, is it safe?

Tags: ether, evm

I am completely new to Ethereum. 
I read a lot of articles and have a question. 
As far as I understood, one can develop smart contracts in Ethereum that are like executable programs. In these programs one can make a transaction.

For example I want to send 5 Ether to Bob. This is a transaction. Now, I am going to develop a program that compiles on EVM and in this program I send 5 Ether to Bob.

Now my question: I can code anything I want. If I have only 5 Ether in my balance, but I am going to spend 500 Ether to Bob, who will read and check my code and decide how many Ether I can spend or not ? In Bitcoin nodes or miner can check the blockchain and look, how many Bitcoin you have spent and you still have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nodes in Ethereum perform that same function as you mentioned in bitcoin (validating transactions). The code of the smart contracts and their state is stored in the blockchain (just like the transaction outputs are stored in Bitcoin's blockchain).

When a smart contract call is executed, the Ethereum nodes validate that the transaction happens exactly according to the logic of the smart contract. If any node tries to cheat the logic that is stored in the blockchain, then it will be rejected by the rest of the network (just like bitcoin nodes do checks to make sure you have enough balance).

Of course if you write bad logic in your smart contracts, then there can be issues. But with ethereum 'code is law'. If the code says it can be done, it can be done; if the code says it can't be done, it can't be done.

Comment: So when I write a smart contract, other nodes can see my code ?

Comment: Yes, your code is compiled and stored in the blockchain.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So in Bitcoin you can make a transaction, but in Ethereum, you can make a transaction only by programming a smart contract that contains the transaction?

Comment: There are projects like 'Enigma', 'TrueBit' and 'Golem' (and some others even), where the code you write isn't stored and executed on the blockchain directly. These projects are doing this for scalabbility or privacy reasons.

Comment: I see, thank you, can you please have a look at my 3 rd commenct regarding to transactions?

Comment: You can make transactions in Ethereum directly (without a smart contract), by sending Ether (the currency). But the term 'transaction' means anything that changes the state of the blockchain. So deploying code is a transaction, sending a token (like with an erc20 contract) is a transaction. Creating a cryptokitten is a transaction, etc. If you are a programmer I suggest you look at https://cryptozombies.io/ , the practical experience will help you understand.

Comment: But then I don't need programming smart contracts ? If I want to make a transaction to BOb, I just make a transaction, that's it, no need for programming a smart contract, right ? Then the nodes check my transaction and a miner put this transaction into a block and mines it?

Comment: You need to program smart contracts if you want to make systems with unique logic. (take a look at the cryptozomies tutorial I linked to you in the previous comment :) ). But yes, if you are not a programmer, you will never need to program smart contracts. Smart contracts are for people who want to make new applications.

Comment: And these new applications does not have to contain transactions, right ? I can write smart contracts that does not contain a transaction but something else

Comment: Let us (for simplicity) say we develop a voting application on Ethereum. Then we would write a smart contract that counts how many votes each candidate gets. Each time someone votes they create a transaction (remember, transactions are just when the state changes). If you wanted to know the address of all the nodes, you wouldn't need a smart contract, you could write a python script (or in any other language). Smart contracts are needed if you want, trusted (actually the correct term is trustless), secure computation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81691/discussion-between-blnpwr-and-jasoons).

Comment: Could you please join the discussion, as I have more questions?